# VBA: How to change the range in a formula depending on the number of populated cells in a particular column?

Tags: excel, vba

I have over 1000 columns in my dataset. They are all ending in row 375.

Can someone advise how do I create a VBA code which enters a formula in e.g. `A376` and instead of the range being e.g. `A1:A375` it looks for the last instance of data (e.g. `A301`) and the first instance of data in the same column (e.g. `A178`) and enters the formula (for the example AVERAGE) `=AVERAGE(A178:A301)`?

The same would have to happen for all 1000 columns (some kind of loop I guess).

I'd be greatly obliged if someone could advise. Thanks

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: Start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) maybe. Well, what do you mean by the "last instance of data"? Are you dealing with formulas?

Comment: The last instance of data in range A1:A375 for column A is in A301 (the last instance of data = last populated cell) but the first populated cell in column A is A178. It varies across all columns (it's the stock data from Yahoo Finance for many different stocks i.e. over 1000 columns. Sometimes data may start at B2:B370 or in C100:C375.

Comment: Then the link I provided is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you.  It is dynamic, meaning that the exact row count does not matter.  It will add the formula to the next row after the last of the data.  It assumes your headers are in row 1, else you will need to adjust Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Column appropriately.

Now you will need to call the method like so:

```
test ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

or better yet, use the worksheet property (name) found in the properties window in the vba editor when the sheet is selected

```
test Sheet1
```

updated code:

```
Sub test(sht As Worksheet)
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim startCell As Range
    Dim endCell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    
    lastRow = sht.UsedRange.Rows(sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Offset(1, 0).Row
    
    For c = 1 To Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Column
        If IsEmpty(sht.Cells(2, c).Value) = False Then
            Set startCell = sht.Cells(2, c)
        Else
            Set startCell = sht.Cells(1, c).End(xlDown)
        End If
            
        Set endCell = sht.Cells(1048576, c).End(xlUp)
        
        sht.Cells(lastRow, c).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & startCell.Address & ":" & endCell.Address & ")"
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: hi Jeremy, I'll have a look. Thanks

Comment: I get Object Required prompt with this part being highlighted Cells(UsedRange.Rows(sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row, c).Formula = _
            "=AVERAGE(" & startCell.Address & ":" & endCell.Address & ")"

Comment: sorry, i just edited the code, remove "sht.".  I had left it over from my test

Comment: try this one, it also accounts for row 2 being populated which i overlooked earlier

Comment: you have added this code to a module.  you have to specify the sheet.  i will provide you an update where you pass the sheet in as a variable to the method.

Comment: Brilliant work !!! Thank you - you have saved me a lot of time and tons of questions :)